# Como hago para detectar solamente el rectángulo vacío de contornos negros de esta imagen de referencia

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

```py
import cv2
isRectangle = False #Debo volver esta variable a True cuando detecte efectivamente un rectangulo

img=cv2.imread('vision.png') #read image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
Blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),1) #apply blur to roi
Canny=cv2.Canny(Blur,10,50) #apply canny to roi

#Find my contours
contours =cv2.findContours(Canny,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]

cntrRect = []
for i in contours:
        epsilon = 0.05*cv2.arcLength(i,True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(i,epsilon,True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            cv2.drawContours(img,cntrRect,-1,(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.imshow('Image Rect ONLY',img)
            cntrRect.append(approx)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Ese es mi código pero el problema es que detecta muchos mas rectángulos de los que debería (osea solo el grande), además de que no quiero que se detecten rectángulos rellenos solo quiero que se detecten aquellos con contorno.

Esta es una de las imágenes de referencia (hablo de rectángulo porque dependiendo el ángulo de otras imágenes algunos rombos y cuadrados parecen rectángulos, solo por perspectiva)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como comente, mi programa esta fallando y detecta muchos mini rectángulos que no quiero, además de que son rectángulos rellenos y yo solo quiero el rectángulo grande y vacío

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay un problema. Eso es un rectangulo para nuestra mente, pero en realidad si observas es en realidad una linea, espacio, linea, espacio, etc. Nuestra mente junta esas lineas para que veamos un rectangulo, pero es posible hacer que un programa haga eso mismo?

Comment: Además, cual es el largo minimo que deben tener los lados para que se considere que es el rectangulo que buscas? Cual debe ser el grosor de ese cuadrado?

Comment: Ahora te planteo un falso positivo. Ponele que un jugador mira un cuadrado hecho de bloques de carbon en un superllano. Tu programa podría creer que ese es el cuadradito que buscas.

Comment: Intenté ayudarte a eliminar muchos falsos positivos pero no pude hacerlo. Sin embargo, te diré que intenté. Puedes calcular el centro de la imagen con `height, width, _ = img.shape center_img = (width//2, height//2)` y asumir que el rectangulo que buscas SIEMPRE contendrá el centro de la imagen. Esto parece cierto para minecraft.

Comment: @DanteS. Estuve intentando y llegue a algo usando threshold pero cuenta con la falla de algunos bloques, lo que estoy haciendo es tomar con que parametros se ve el cuadrado solo segun el tipo de bloque, y me encontre que hacer un promedio que funcione con un filtrado HSV para todos no sirve, pero los valores del HSV encontro hasta ahora que se podrian agrupar en coordenadas (H,S,V), y podria hacer una comprobacion de que si una imagen es similar a uno de esos promedios, el cuadrado se podria diferenciar

Comment: Lo que complica es que es muy dificil usar una maskBlackvis = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask= maskBlack) porque los valores que filtrarian al cuadrado del entorno dependen del piso y no giran sobre un promedio general

Comment: Te voy a ser sincero. No entendí lo que me dijiste por que no tengo ese tipo de conocimiento. Sin embargo, te sirve la idea que propuse de detectar si el centro de la imagen está dentro de uno de los cuadrados?

Comment: creo que hare una tabla de datos tabulando los puntos (H,S,V) para cada una de las muchas imagenes que tengo. Quizas con un metodo de k-means clustering pueda hallar los promedios de HSV con los que podria filtrar la imagen de fondo y quedarme con solo el cuadrado central, para luego usar este detector

Comment: Lo del centro de la imagen, tiene la complicacion de que el bloque del centro de la imagen puede ser de colores muy diversos, y costaria filtrarlo aun

Comment: Entiendo! Entonces el problema sería detectar correctamente el cuadrado que selecciona el bloque.

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es juntar muchas imagenes, usar el threasholding sobre todas, o/y ajustar parametros HSV (jugar con esa escala de color) y asi filtrar el cuadrado, y como eso no funciona para todas las superficies lo ideal seria poner 3 o 4 if donde compare coincidencias uno a uno, el tema es encontrar promedios donde se abarque a la posibilidad de filtrar el cuadrado negro en la mayor cantidad de bloques posibles dejando las lineas de este continuas

Comment: thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

tendre que jugar con que 30 o 255 son los mas apropiados para la mayoria de las imagenes y sacar el cuadrado en cada una de ellas

Comment: Aunque quizas hay un mejor metodo para detectar esos cuadrados vacios sin depender de cambiar las escalas HSV, juntar datos, hallar promedios donde varios puntos se junten, y usa 4 o 5 if probando en cada uno si estan o no los parametros que hallan el cuadrado. Siento que es demasiado rebuscado como para ser una buena solucion. Quizas a alguien de stack se le ocurra algo mejo

Answer (score 1):

La mejor forma que se me ocurre utilizando openCV en python es encontrando líneas y filtrando los puntos no contenidos en las líneas.

Una observación inicial es que `cv2.HoughLines()` detecta puntos blancos que estén contenidos en una misma línea con un límite inferior del número de puntos. Así que el primer paso es que solo los puntos de interés sean blancos. Por lo que he aplicado el siguiente filtro:

```py
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dst=cv2.Laplacian(gray, cv2.CV_8UC1)
```

[image: Imagen filtrada 1]

Ahora detectamos las líneas con (segmento de código modificado de [documentación: Hough Line Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html)):

```py
# %% HoughLines

# Matriz de ceros con mismas dimenciones que dst
out=np.zeros_like(dst)

# Input:
#   imagen, 
#   pixeles de resolución,
#   np.pi/180 -> 1 grado de resolución angular
#   mínimo 50 puntos por línea
#  **Nota importante** los puntos de interés son los blancos,
#   ojo con usar puntos negros en fondo blanco, no funcionará
lines = cv2.HoughLines(dst, 1, np.pi / 180, 50, None, 0, 0)
# Salida:
#   radio rho, y angulo theta
#  ver: https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/vmwe4kcb

# Dibujar rectas [fuente:https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html]
if lines is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        rho = lines[i][0][0]
        theta = lines[i][0][1]
        a = math.cos(theta)
        b = math.sin(theta)
        x0 = a * rho
        y0 = b * rho
        pt1 = (int(x0 + 1000*(-b)), int(y0 + 1000*(a)))
        pt2 = (int(x0 - 1000*(-b)), int(y0 - 1000*(a)))
        cv2.line(out, pt1, pt2, (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

```py
# %% Considerar solo los puntos de las líneas
result=cv2.bitwise_and(dst,dst,mask = out)
show(result)
```

[image: Líneas detectadas]

Filtrando o eliminando los puntos que está por fuera de las líneas de interés se obtiene:

```py
# %% Considerar solo los puntos de las líneas
result=cv2.bitwise_and(dst,dst,mask = out)
show(result)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para conectar la línea y no sean puntos separados, usamos:

```py
# %% Poner más gruesa y conectar lineas débiles

# opción 1
e_im = cv2.dilate(result, kernel, iterations=5) 
d_im = cv2.erode(e_im, kernel, iterations=4)
# opción 2
# kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,5))
# e_im = cv2.dilate(result, kernel, iterations=3) 
# d_im = cv2.erode(e_im, kernel, iterations=2)

show(d_im)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya terminando filtramos para obtener los contornos con un área superior a los puntos de ruido, además como el rectángulo tiene contorno interno un filtro adicional es mostrar solo los componentes que tienen hijos:

```py
# %% (Alternativa 1) connectedComponentsWithStats con área mínima
nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(d_im, connectivity=4)
# Output:
# nb_components -> número de etiquetas o grupos detectados
# output-> matriz 2D (shape) multi-etiqueta
# stats -> contiene (x top left, y top left, width, height, area de la sombra)
# centroids-> ubicación (x,y) del centroide

sizes = stats[1:, -1]; nb_components = nb_components - 1

min_size = 1100 # Este tamaño es variable, yo he puesto 1000 en mi caso

img2 = np.zeros((output.shape))

for i in range(0, nb_components):
    if sizes[i] >= min_size and stats[i+1][0]>0:
        # matriz booleana para cada etiqueta, activa una agrupacion completa
        img2[output == i + 1] = 255
        # cv2.rectangle(img2,(stats[i+1][0],stats[i+1][1]),(stats[i+1][0]+stats[i+1][2],stats[i+1][1]+stats[i+1][3]),(155,155,155),3)
Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img2) , 'L')
```

```py
# %% Dibujar solo el borde que tenga hijos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397592/only-find-contour-without-child
ChildContour = hierarchy [0, :,2]
indices=(ChildContour!=-1).nonzero()[0]

ncontours=tuple(contours[i] for i in indices)
imgOut=img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(imgOut, ncontours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
show(imgOut)
```

##### Resultado final

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:**
En la última etapa agregué para ajustar `and stats[i+1][0]>0`, la idea fue por eliminar también los contornos que están conectados a los bordes, en este caso específico solo se usó el borde izquierdo, si es necesario se puede ignorar los contornos que estén conectados a todos los bordes de la imagen.

En todo caso al no tener contornos internos sería filtrado en la última parte por no tener contornos hijos.

Comment: Algo que puedes asumir para eliminar aun más falsos positivos es que el cuadrado encontrado contendrá el centro de la imagen.

Comment: Como puedo posicionarme en un figura en especifico, en una posision, ya que mi imagen me muestra varios rectangulos y yo solo ocupo seleccionar uno en especifico?